# How Do I Convert RGBA to BC3 (DXT5) at runtime with DirectX?

Tags: graphics, 3d, textures, directx-11

I'm trying to use DirectX for converting Texture from RGBA pixel format to BC3.
I tried squish but I'ts too slow for me maybe there is a way doing it using DirectX so it will happen on the GPU?

I don't want to rely on specific hardware also (nVidia/AMD).

Answer (score 2):

Most optimal would be to implement a real-time compression algorithm on GPU. There are no such compressors for BC3, but you could extend a BC1 compressor which is conceptually similar. See classic BC1 real-time compression paper [Waveren06](http://mrelusive.com/publications/papers/Real-Time-Dxt-Compression.pdf) and it's GPU implementation [Tranchida10](http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc10/slides/Tranchida_TextureCompressionInRealtime.pdf).

Comment: Wavern's solution also works for DXT5 which is BC3. See [this Intel article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-cpu-dxt-compression). With DirectX 11 Feature Level 11.x hardware, you might also consider using BC7 per [this Intel article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-ispc-texture-compressor).  Keep in mind that these 'Fast Block Compress' schemes tend to have much lower quality that traditional 'offline' compression which should be your first choice. See also [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926).

Comment: Actually Intel ISPC BC7 (from the second link) isn't that fast as it's an offline compressor. Furthermore BC7 isn't well suited for real-time compression, as due to multiple block modes it has a very large search space.

Comment: Thanks everyone, This was very helpful.
I decided to go with DirectXTex - using the compress function.
Since I'm working with .net (monogame) i wrote a small wrapper and it works great. 
The interesting thing i discovered tough is that when working with ThreadPool compression go  much faster then creating my own threads.